# iOS UnsafePointer memory deallocation

Tags: c++, objective-c, swift, allocation, unsafe-pointers

I am interfacing with a hardware device that runs C++ code and sends live data almost 10 times per second to the iOS device.

I have a Swift method like this:

```
func m16b_to_mE0(_ pointer: UnsafePointer<m16bytes_t>) -> UnsafePointer<metrics_E0>? {
     return UnsafeRawPointer(pointer).bindMemory(to: metrics_E0.self, capacity: MemoryLayout<metrics_E0>.size)
}
```

Where `m16bytes_t` is

```
typedef uint8_t m16bytes_t[16];
```

And `metrics_E0` is

```
struct metrics_E0 {
    uint8_t   tag;
    uint8_t   hr;
    uint16_t  c_speed;
    uint16_t  c_max_speed;
    uint16_t  c_met_power;
    uint16_t  c_speed_intensity;
    uint16_t  c_hr_exertion;
    uint8_t   hr_avg;
    u3bytes_t c_acc_met_power; //typedef uint8_t u3bytes_t[3];
};
```

The above `m16b_to_mE0` method is called almost 10 times per second, for about two hours, more or less.

My question is: is it required to deallocate / deinitialize memory for each `UnsafeRawPointer` after `bindMemory` to `metrics_E0`? If yes, how?

What happens if I don't take care to manually deallocate / deinitialize the `UnsafePointer` type from the memory?

Comment: `bindMemory` does not allocate anything, it is (roughly speaking) what a type cast is in C or C++.

Comment: Consider using obj-c instead of swift for the task. There will be no need for UnsafeRawPointer/bindMemory/...

Answer (score 1):

`bindMemory` doesn't change the ownership of the allocated memory, it's goal is to allow you to peak at the contents of the memory. Unless specified in the documentation of the C++ library that you need to manually release the received pointer, then you should not need to worry about this.

You can do some memory profiling if you want to be sure, and to monitor the memory usage of your application. Or, if you have access to the C++ code, you could set a breakpoint on the `m16b_to_mE0` function and go through the stacktrace until you reach the C++ zone, and check what happens later with the pointer that was sent to your method.

Note that releasing the memory of that buffer might require some library dedicated functions for deallocations, instead of the standard ones, however this should be specified in the library documentation.